# How to set unique data for a node in ohai or attributes during bootstrap a node or after this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am using EC2 machines and I want that for each node that associated with chef server have information of its AWS tags (Eg. name etc).

One way is to set this information in ohai and use this in chef recipe.
How to set this information in ohai data ?

or

How to set some attributes (these represent AWS tags) different for each node,so we can use these attributes in chef recipe.

Is there any way to fetch tags of EC2 node in chef recipe itself without depend on above two ?

Comment: I'm unsure of what your question is, there's an EC2 plugin for ohai, does it not store the tags or is the problem about how to let this pugin run ? (for the latest you need a hint file /etc/chef/ohai/hints/ec2.json on the node if I remember correctly)

Comment: I don't know, how to use this plugin. Is there any way to store some attributes unique for each node ? so i can store tags as attributes.

Comment: Using this ohai plugin is as simple as doing `touch etc/chef/ohai/hints/ec2.json` and then check attributes populated under node['ec2'] (IIRC). If you want to just tag a node then use the `tag` feature in recipe or else. But all in all I think you should really take some time on http://learn.chef.io to get around the bases with chef.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately EC2 tags are not included in the EC2 instance metadata for some reason. This means that tags are not easily available for Ohai to query. You could use EC2 IAM roles and a custom Ohai plugin to implement this, but either the IAM policy would be amazingly complex or you would need to weight the security risks of nodes being able to see each others' tags.

tl;dr EC2 tags are not available in this way.

Comment: can I store EC2 tags as attribute on chef server unique for each node ?

Comment: okay i will do it manually , but how to set these attributes unique for each node ?